# Cannot create a new connection is sqldeveloepr

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Programming. I am learning JAVA and for DB i wanted to learn Oracle so I downloaded sqldeveloper from Oracle website. It was a zip file so I didnot have to install anything, simply extracted it. When I open the sqldeveloper and try to make a new connection, it shows error.

Test failed: IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection.

I am not sure what to put in username and pwd. and i am also not sure if i have to connect this to jdk or jre or set classpath for database.

Can anyone help me?? I have uploaded the snapshot of the error too.

[image]

Comment: Have you only installed SQL Developer (which is just a client), or have you also downloaded and installed the Oracle RDBMS server software? You have to have a database to connect to. You're trying to connect to one running on your PC. If you don't have one on your PC, do you have access to one somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded a client.

You did NOT download the server component though - the actual database.

SQL Developer just allows you to work with an existing database.

No worries, you're not that far away. You have several options.

Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) - it's completely free.

We also have a VirtualBox appliance you can use for personal learning purposes, also completely free.

I talk about this and give [step by step instructions here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if oracle service, TNSListener service is up and running before trying to make any new connection from sql developer.

Even if TNS Service is down , connection can not be established with oracle instance.